# erlang on 64bit ubuntu

Tags: erlang, cryptography, libssl

First, there is not specif 64bit download FOR ERLANG

When I tried to make with crypto enabled, I get this error

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/axon/erlang-src/otp_src_R14B01/lib/crypto'
=== Entering application crypto
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/axon/erlang-src/otp_src_R14B01/lib/crypto/src'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `opt'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/axon/erlang-src/otp_src_R14B01/lib/crypto/src'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/axon/erlang-src/otp_src_R14B01/lib/crypto/c_src'
make -f x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/Makefile TYPE=opt
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/axon/erlang-src/otp_src_R14B01/lib/crypto/c_src'
/usr/bin/install -c -d ../priv/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 
gcc -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -o ../priv/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/crypto.so ../priv/obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/crypto.o  -Wl,-R/usr/local/ssl/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib64 -Wl,-R/usr/sfw/lib64 -Wl,-R/opt/local/lib64 -Wl,-R/usr/lib64 -Wl,-R/usr/pkg/lib64 -Wl,-R/usr/local/openssl/lib64 -Wl,-R/usr/lib/openssl/lib64 -Wl,-R/usr/openssl/lib64 -Wl,-R/usr/local/ssl/lib64 -Wl,-R/usr/lib/ssl/lib64 -Wl,-R/usr/ssl/lib64 -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/sfw/lib -Wl,-R/opt/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/pkg/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/openssl/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib/openssl/lib -Wl,-R/usr/openssl/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib/ssl/lib -Wl,-R/usr/ssl/lib -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lcrypto
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [../priv/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/crypto.so] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/axon/erlang-src/otp_src_R14B01/lib/crypto/c_src'
make[3]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/axon/erlang-src/otp_src_R14B01/lib/crypto/c_src'
make[2]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/axon/erlang-src/otp_src_R14B01/lib/crypto'
make[1]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/axon/erlang-src/otp_src_R14B01/lib'
make: *** [libs] Error 2
```

I learnt this is an issue with lib_ssl itself, some other guys are also having this issue. Someone recommends I edit a crypto header file before installing lib_ssl, I did but that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: You can find a binary download for 64-bit Ubuntu here: http://www.erlang-solutions.com/section/132/download-erlang-otp

Answer (score 1):

Looks like You are missing a prerequisite ("libssl-dev").

Maybe have a look at my "[installation guide](http://boris.muehmer.de/2010/10/16/installing-erlangotp-r14b-on-ubuntu-from-source/)" and compare it with Your setup. Even if this "guide" is for R14, I use it for R13 and all other R14 versions as well.

Comment: I cant use apt-get because the server is not hooked up to the internet. Know where I can pull the source of libssl-dev?

Comment: hmmm... maybe it is on the DVD image... or check launchpad: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+package/libssl-dev  ... I haven't done an "offline" installation, yet... sorry.